# Confusion about word tense when ordering in a restaurant

Tags: phrase-usage, tense, auxiliary-verbs

When ordering in a restaurant, which of the following are ways to order tea?

> I would like to have a tea.
>
> I will have a tea.
>
> Can I get a tea?
>
> Could you get me a tea?
>
> Tea.

I think they mean the same thing. Are any of them incorrect?

Comment: It depends on whether you are **asking for** tea or **planning to make some for yourself**, and whether you want it  **now** or **later**.

Comment: If I am ordering a tea in a restaurant what should I use.

Comment: in a restaurant, I'd go with "I'd like tea", "I'll have a tea" or "Could I get a tea". Add "Please" to the end of of those & you'll get a tea & a smile ;-) I wouldn't specifically ask if they can get it [your last example] as it's pretty much certain you won't be made to fetch it yourself.

Comment: If somebody is asking me about tea or coffee.Can I answer it as.I will have a tea. or I would like to have a tea. or just say, "tea".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the options will result in the waiter bringing you tea, so in that sense they mean the same thing. However, in terms of politeness I'd go with:

> I would like to have a tea.

Or even:

> I'll have tea, please.

If you ask for tea, you might occasionally find yourself with a sarcastic waiter who'll answer "no" as a joke, but they'll still bring you tea.

Answer (score -1):

The meaning is different. You can find more information about it [here](http://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-should-could-and-would/).

In terms of formality, “can you” is the most casual, “could you” is more polite and “would you” is the most formal and polite.

Comment: Please post short answers such as this one as a comment instead.

Comment: I am new user, I can not write comments! Thank you.

Comment: Given link explain _Difference between Should, Could, and Would_, that doesn't answer the _OP_'s question.